# Thunderbolt to USB3.0 to eSata

Tags: connector, adapter, thunderbolt

I have a camera that its only output port is thunderbolt.
The laptop that I want to connect the camera is a windows laptop and it has only these input ports: USB 2.0, USB 3.0, eSata, ethernet and a miniDisplay port.
I have also a adaptor from thundebolt to firewire.
I searched in internet and I haven't found a fairly cheap and easy solution (adapter).
Any ideas?

Comment: The short answer is *almost* certainly no. Thunderbolt is, for all intents and purposes, either PCI-e or displayPort. Since the camera doesn't claim it has a displayport output, it means it's likely acting as a PCI-e device. The only way that's going to work is if hooked up to a PCI-e connection.

Comment: @conner: Just to make sure: Did you list all inputs? E.g. the laptop does not have a expresscard slot? (That has a single PCI-e lane allowing expresscard/34 to thunderbolt).

Comment: Unfortunately the laptop has not a expresscard slot.

Comment: The last idea I have is checking the manual for any free internal mini-PCIe slots and rigging an impromptu expresscard from one of those and a USB port. Theoretically that might work.

The practical answer is use a different laptop or a different camera, since they simply do not match. @Fake Name's comment is sadly correct.

Comment: I don't think there is any guarantee that the laptop will have the right drivers to talk to the camera even if you solve the 'electrical connection' problem. Even if the drivers come from the manufacturer of the adapter, there might be issues or your specific OS unless the manufacturer gives that assurance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thunderbolt and USB are two different protocols. A simple adapter will never suffice to interpret between the two signals. Instead, you need an active converter device, which exist, but are expensive.

While Intel developed the Thunderbolt port, and a few PC makers included thunderbolt ports in their high-end devices, all but Apple have dropped this for lack of demand and in favor of USB3. This means that even the converters are going to be expensive.